# Using setxkbmap to switch keyboard layouts

Tags: pantheon, keyboard-layout

For several years now I have been switching the keyboard layout in all Linux distributions as follows:
The first fix en (caps lock), the second - ru (shift + caps lock)

```
setxkbmap -option "grp:switch,grp:shift_caps_switch,grp_led:scroll" -layout "us,ru"
```

I really would like to continue using this combination, but for the Pantheon environment this method does not work. Please help.

Comment: Attempt to use X configuration files failed. Settings do not work.